# Optimizing Simple Truss Member Angle

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I am trying to optimize the angles alpha and theta, for which members of truss would carry the less loads. Given is location of force and value of force.

Problem is, that I get contradictory equations, where decrease of one angle is favorable for one member but unfavorable for other one (as more vertical member gets, more vertical loads it will carry). So I came up with the equation, but I am unable to solve it for angles to get minimum force values in the members.

On one hand, I know that it has something to do with derivatives, because if we set derivative of force with respect to angle to zero, I think one should be able to get the most efficient angle. But, there are 2 equations and I am not sure if this approach is correct or how to set up derivative equation.

Any ideas you may suggest?

Thanks.

I am attaching the drawing of the truss structure below

[image]

Comment: I assume $L_1$ and $L_2$ are constants? or is the length of the rods constant?

Comment: I changed the task and refined it a little bit. What is given is $ L_{3} $ and $ F $ , idea is to find optimal angles with absolute value of $ F_{AB} + $$ F_{BC} $ is minimum.

Comment: Is also H constant?

Comment: No, $H$ is the height, which is defined by the angles and $L_{3}$ as shown in equation 3 in the Geometry part of the Figure attached. Only known quantities (constants) are $F$ and $L_{3}$, angles are to be found and all other geometries, as well as internal forces in members are defined by angles.

Comment: It's an underconstrained solution, you'll minimise the axial forces by maximising H, ad infinitum. Both will tend to F/2.

Comment: It would be true for "springs in parallel", in this example if you maximize $H$, then you decrease $\theta$ and increase $\alpha$. By decreasing $\theta$ from equation $2$, $sin\theta$ goes to $0$ therefore you maximize $F_{AC}$, while by increasing $\alpha$, from equation $1$, $cos\alpha$ goes to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ therefore you also maximize $F_{BC}$. Contrary, minimizing the axial forces was the goal, while your solution suggests maximizing them in some sense.